# GitHub - Is possible to create pull requests before past pull requests or issues before past issues?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I created a project for a GitHub repository and I'm doing the project management there with tasks. I've already made some issues and pull requests but in order to preserve history logic, I would like to sort them differently. Is this possible? To update the number and order of history?

Comment: I'm not clear how issue and pull request numbers are relevant here. Sometimes it makes sense to work on issue 100 before issue 5. Sometimes it makes sense to merge PR 12 before PR 11. It's very difficult to know what order thing should happen when you're creating these things.

Comment: (And, no, it's not possible to choose the number an issue or PR will have.)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub itself cannot not "sort PR differently".

As a project manager, you can list those PR and sort them yourself, using the PR commit message with a naming convention in order to do that sort.
In other words, the logical order you are after can come from convention in the PR message, not from a PR reorder feature from GitHub.